# How to create a template that links from one MediaWiki to another?

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to create a linkage between two media wiki. Specifically, a template that links to an specific article on the other wiki.

I would like to write

> See {{otherwiki|Some thing}}

The template `otherwiki` should convert the above to

> [http://linkto.other.wik/Some_thing Some thing]

The template I wrote works pretty well for single-word terms, and it works if I write `Some_thing`, but I can't get it to work for phrases that contain whitespace.

> [https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/{{{1}}} {{{1}}}]

How do I fix the above template to make it support whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to set up [interwiki links](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterwiki) to the target wiki. With that, you can either write your links directly as e.g. `[[otherwiki:Some thing|]]`, or you can encapsulate that into a template (`[[otherwiki:{{{1}}}|]]`), so the syntax would be exactly as you wanted.

Another option is to use [the magic word `{{urlencode}}`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aMagic_words#urlencode):

```
[https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/{{urlencode:{{{1}}}|WIKI}} {{{1}}}]
```